# CSS being overriden by by a:-webkit-any-link use agent stylsheet

Tags: html, css, webkit

I am working with a page with a ton of lists and links. I am trying to style each on a little differently, but fonts and color keep being overridden by a style a:-webkit-any-link user agent stylesheet. I have no idea where that even came from. I have tried styling my divs using classes, ids and even inline styling but none of them override the user agent stylesheet.

```
    <div id="dafoot">
        <ul id="footList">
            <li class="footTop">
                    <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="footTop">
                    <a href="bikes.html">Bikes</a>
                    <ul class="footUnder">
                        <li class="footSubBottom"><a href="mBikes.php">Moutain</a></li>
                        <li class="footSubBottom"><a href="rBikes.php">Road</a></li>
                        <li class="footSubBottom"><a href="kBikes.php">Kids</a></li>
                        <li class="footSubBottom"><a href="sBikes.php">Specialty</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                    <li class="footTop"><a href="activities.php">Activities</a>
                    <ul class="footUnder">
                        <li class="footSubBottom"><a href="seminars.html">Seminars</a></li>    
                        <li class="footSubBottom"><a href="cff.html">Cycle for Fit.</a></li>
                        <li class="footSubBottom"><a href="choose.html">Choose your bike</a></li>        
                        <li class="footSubBottom"><a href="rides.html">Rides</a></li>    
                    </ul>
                </li>
                    <li class="footTop"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
                    <ul class="footUnder">                                
                        <li class="footSubBottom"><a href="visit.html">Visit us</a></li>
                        <li class="footSubBottom"><a href="info.html">Contact Info</a></li>        
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li class="footTop"><a href="qa.html">Q & A</a>
                    <ul class="footUnder">
                     <li class="footSubBottom"><a href="faq.html">FAQ's</a></li> 
                     <li class="footSubBottom"><a href="ask.php">Ask a Q</a></li>
                    </ul> 
                </li>
                <li class="footTop"><a href="about.html">About</a>
                    <ul class="footUnder">
                        <li class="footSubBottom"><a href="history.html">History</a></li>    
                        <li class="footSubBottom"><a href="staff.html">Staff</a></li>
                        <li class="footSubBottom"><a href="employ.html">Employment</a></li>   
                    </ul>
                </li>
        </ul>    
        <a href="owner.php">Owner Portal</a> 
        </div>
```

CSS

```
     /**/
    /* Styling for the footer list */
    /**/

#dafoot{
float: left;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: 10px;
margin-top: auto;
line-height: 15px;
width: 1077.5px;
margin-top: 10px;
position:relative;
color: white;
background-color: white;
}

#footlist{
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #ffbb00;
    list-style: none;
}

a .footTop{
    color: white;
    font-family: Georgia;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow..... I didn't capitalize an L in footList. Working now. Hey noobs out there, check your spelling and capitalizing before you post on stack overflow.

Comment: Thought about it, except this really is the answer, not a comment on my question.